# UIScrollview setContentSize doesn't get set

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I've got a `UIScrollview` with some labels, images, a mapview, tableview and a webview in it.

```
scr2 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 320, 0, 320, 335)];
scr2.delegate = self;
```

i = the number of pages.

Edit: `scr2` is a `UIScrollView` in a `UIScrollView`, that's why I use `i * 320` for x position.

After I added all the components I set the `contentSize`:

```
[scr2 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, dateLabel.frame.size.height + nameLabel.frame.size.height + descWebView.frame.size.height + tableViewSize.height + addressLabel.frame.size.height + myMapView.frame.size.height + 100)];
```

The UIWebView gets dynamically resized in `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView
{ 
    aWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;

    frame.size.width = 301;
    frame.size.height = 1;

    aWebView.frame = frame;       
    frame.size.height = aWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height;    
    aWebView.frame = frame;       

    [scr2 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, dateLabel.frame.size.height + nameLabel.frame.size.height + descWebView.frame.size.height + tableViewSize.height + addressLabel.frame.size.height + myMapView.frame.size.height + 100)];
}
```

So here the `descWebView` gets resized to fit the content. After that, I set the `contentSize` from our scrollview to the new dimensions, with the proper height from `descWebView` this time.

And here's my problem. The scrollview doesn't react at all to `setContentSize`. Nothing wrong with my height by the way, because if I set the `contentSize` to `0, 100` it gets ignored as well.

/Edit

scr2 doesn't react to scrollEnabled or anything else as well.

Comment: Your scrollView's horizontal position depends on the number of pages?

Comment: The frame you set when you initialize the uiscrollview looks wrong. This should be the position of the visible frame in the parent. I don't think you should be multiplying the x origin by i?

Comment: I forgot to add that `scr2` is as `UIScrollView` in a `UIScrollView`, just ignore the setFrame bit.